# how do i test if all the elements of a string fulfill the same condition in a list

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary, conditional-statements

If I have a string `'abc'`, and a dictionary `{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':0}`, and I want to execute some operation only if all the elements of the string are values in the dictionary, and all the values of the keys are > 0, how can I test it?

I have this loop:

```
 def f(adic, astring):
   for i in astring:
     if i in adic.keys() and adic[i] > 0:
         adic[i] -= 1
     return adic
```

and for the input in the function

```
f({'a': 1, 'i': 3, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 'y': 2}, "hair")
```

i get the expected output:

```
{'a': 0, 'i': 2, 'h': 0, 'r': 0, 't': 1, 'y': 2}
```

but if i test it again with the same output i get this:

```
{'a': 0, 'i': 1, 'h': 0, 'r': 0, 't': 1, 'y': 2}
```

and I'm expecting to get this:

```
{'a': 0, 'y': 2, 'r': 0, 't': 1, 'i': 2, 'h': 0}
```

because I want to execute this only if all the elements of the string appear in the dictionary and the values are not currently equal to 0.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to write `isValidWord` (i.e. is this MIT 6.00x PS4)?

Comment: Then you should bear in mind 1. your function shouldn't mutate `hand` and 2. re: use of StackOverflow *"From the 6.00x course staff, please do not engage in this type of cheating. First off, this is a violation of the Honor Code. Secondly, the actions of the few of you engaging in this behavior puts a bad face on all edX staff and students. Please do not ask for homework help on Stack Overflow. Use our forums, and when our forums are closed, follow the Honor Code and do your own work."*

Comment: lol man i am not doing it for getting grade, the course is already in the week 8, and i'm doing it by myself, i'm just stuck in this and i was asking for something punctual, how you have the courage of coming here calling me cheater if i'm just trying to learn programming, and its clear i'm not asking people for doing my homework, it was just a punctual question

Comment: I very carefully *didn't* call you a cheater, I just told you to bear it in mind. If you had been more up-front about what you were doing (mentioning the course, not trying to hide the function signature, etc.) I would have been less suspicious of your motives; it is absolutely **not** clear that you're not asking people to do your homework.

Comment: i changue it for let it clear that the first input in the function was a list, and the second one a string, because i though that this would make easier to understand my problem giving people here might not know the actual problem i was working on, actually the thing i was stuck with had nothing to do with the rest of the problem

Comment: Well that didn't really work, for three reasons: 1. you didn't change the names *inside* the function, making it unclear what was even going on; 2. you removed the docstring (that actually *included* the types of the arguments); and 3. you refer to a dictionary as a list.

Comment: and i though nobody cares here if im doing a course, i though this site it's just for programming questions and thats what i had, i didnt put the entire problem expecting someone to solve it in any moment, i just put a punctual question, if you read carefully you'll see that for all im asking for is for know how to put in my loop a condition that says that all the elements of the string should be in the list without any of those going less than 0, and the problem in that course is asking me for all the loop, i just had one thing i couldn't know how to writte, but i knew was that what i need

Comment: yep i noticed the mistakes, but they were because im begining with programming, and im mistaking concepts, im really bad at this, i never did it before i just want to learn it because i like it so far

Comment: i didnt post it in any meaningful intention and never i though that this could dissapoint someone, i apologize you if you are offended by this, but i was just posting this for the merely objective of learning,and i still think i didnt put any homework here for someone to solve, i just posted something PUNCTUAL for see how its done and learn how to do it

Comment: and i called list because i was thinking of hand.keys(), ill try to correct it

Comment: Thank you, I would appreciate that. If you could clarify that your question is how can you check that the dictionary contains sufficient letters *without* mutating it, that would be good too. I am neither disappointed nor offended, just trying to keep the quality of contributions here high. [Off-topic: I think you mean *concise* (short and meaningful) not *punctual* (timely).]

Comment: how it is not clear, if i already writte the loop by myself and i was trying to know how to do something for implemente it to my loop, something concise that i already knew what i was but i didnt know how to writte? how is not clear?

Comment: yes i mean concise then, im not native

**it's already edited

Comment: You still have `word` and `hand` inside the function. You can't just pass the `.keys()`, because you're also checking the values (`alist[i]`). Your function is incorrectly indented, so returns on the first character of `astring`/`word`. Please test your code before posting, and ensure that your inputs and outputs match the description; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: my question is how can i writte a condition that sees if all the elements on a string are in the keys of a dictionary as long as they acomplish the condition that their value is >0

Comment: But it's not just that, is it? You want to ensure that the *count* (hint!) of each character in the string is smaller than the corresponding value for that character in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually directly executing your decrementation after checking every single letter, but what you want to do (if i get you right) is to first check whether all elements of the string appear within the dictionary (despite what you said, you are not operating on a list) and are greater 0, and then do the decrementation.

So, a possible solution maybe could be something like this (

```
 def f(hand, word):

     # check first whether all conditions are fulfilled,
     # return hand unmodified if not

     for i in word:

         if i not in hand.keys():

             return hand

         if hand[i] <= 0:

             return hand

     # if conditions are fulfilled, do the decrementation

     for i in word:

             hand[i] -= 1

     return hand
```

Comment: Just realized I forgot to alter the if-condition, fixed this now!